# URL From Plist to Detail View Controller's Web View

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, url, plist

I have a band application where the app needs to have instrument scales on it. To do this I am trying to have a PList file with the Name of the Scale and a Description. I have researched and all I can find is for passing images, not URL's. I have the plist done. Here is a part of it:

[image: /Users/grandslam700/Desktop/Screen Shot 2013-04-01 at 7.05.50 PM.png]
And I also have a table view getting the Name and the Scale Part of the Plist file.

[image]

What I can't figure out how to do is, how do I drill down into a Detail View controller and then load the URL for the clicked Table  View Cell into a UI Webview, Here is the Code from the .m of the Main Table view:

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "DetailView.h"
@interface TableViewController ()
@end

@implementation TableViewController
@synthesize content = _content;

-(NSArray *)content
{
    if (!_content) {
        _content = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Scales" ofType:@"plist"]];
    }
return _content;
}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Detail"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
    }
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.content count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Scale"];

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
/*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
  */
}

@end
```

`
If anybody has any idea how to do this, please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
 detailViewController.webLink = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"URL"];//webLink is NSStringProperty in DetailViewController.h
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Load UIWebView inside viewDidLoad of DetailViewController use XIB

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.webLink]]];
}
```

About how to push to WebViewController, refer sample code:
https://github.com/lequysang/github_zip/blob/master/TestTapOnWeb.zip

With storyboard.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
     NSString *webLink = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"URL"];//webLink is NSStringProperty in DetailViewController.h
        [[segue destinationViewController] setWebLink:webLink];
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work in a storyboard app. As the weblink part isn't working

Comment: I understand that, my problem is that it is now saying that Indexpath is an undeclared Identifier. Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: it is there, i just don't know how to transfer the URL. Here is a copy of it from above: `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Detail"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
    }
}`

Comment: Default code have it: NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

Comment: One more problem, It is now showing, `property webLink not found on object of type DetailViewController` (In the detail View controller .m File). What does this mean?

Comment: Oh, sorry I didnt see the edit, I will try that. I AM REALLY SORRY!:(